# Bash: delete curly braces on a condition

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I want to remove curly braces from the string below, but only if  `*`  is found between them.

I have found a lot of answers on this topic, but in my scenario I want to delete only those braces where the condition is met, i.e. `{*} --> *`.

```
name,apple,price,{50 70 80 80},color,{*}
name,orange,price,{*},color,{80 30 40}
```

expected output:

```
name,apple,price,{50 70 80 80},color,*
name,orange,price,*,color,{80 30 40}
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: perfect .. thanks a lot

Comment: please provide answer, will mark it as resolved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`'s `s` command (as in substitute) – include the curly brackets in the `regexp`, but not in the `replacement`:

```
sed 's/{\*}/*/g'
```

Comment: thanks.. it works.

Answer (score 1):

With just bash

```bsh
line='name,orange,price,{*},color,{80 30 40}'
s='{*}'
echo "${line//"$s"/*}"
```

```
name,orange,price,*,color,{80 30 40}
```

I couldn't figure out how to do the escaping so that the `s` variable was not needed.

Note the double quotes are required, or else you get:

```bsh
$ echo "${line//$s/*}"
name,orange,price,*
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. its useful

Comment: So you don't need `s` the escaping is `echo "${line//{\*\}/*}"`. You need to escape the `*` as it's a character repetition metachar and you need to escape the `}` since otherwise it'd be the end of the `${...}` parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
sed "/{\*}/s/{\*}/*/g" filename
```

output

```
name,apple,price,{50 70 80 80},color,*
name,orange,price,*,color,{80 30 40}
```

Method2

```
awk '$0 ~ "{*}" {gsub (/{\*}/,"*",$0);print }'  filename
```

output

```
name,apple,price,{50 70 80 80},color,*
name,orange,price,*,color,{80 30 40}
```

Comment: wrt the awk command: `$0 ~ "{*}"` is equivalent to just `/{*}/` and both mean "a `}` preceded by zero or more `{`s" so that'll match any line containing a `}`. You don't need the `,$0` at the end of the gsub() as that's the default. Unlike the sed command, the awk command will ONLY print lines that contain a `}`.